# Adding and removing lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need some help on this problem I'm working on. It needs me to write a function that inputs a list and removes any empty lists inside it. This is what I have so far:

```
a = []
b = []

def listmaking(a):
    List = []
    List = input.append()
    List = input.split(" ")
    return List

    for item in a:
        if item!=[]:
            b.append(item)
    print(b)
```

I don't know where I am going wrong here. Any help would be appertained!

Comment: when you `return List` in your function, you don't ever reach to the `for loop` in your function.

Answer (score 3):

To filter out empty lists from a list, all you need to do is

```
new_list = [obj for obj in old_list if obj != []]
```

So, for example:

```
old_list = [[], (), 0, 8, 'hello', '']
new_list = [obj for obj in old_list if obj != []]
print(new_list)
```

outputs

```
[(), 0, 8, 'hello', '']
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems you are a beginner and you might have a hard time understanding 1-line Python codes, below is a modification to your code that works:

```
old_list = [[], (), 0, 8, 'hello', '']

def listmaking(a):
    b = []
    for item in a:
        if item!=[]:
            b.append(item)
    return b

print(listmaking(old_list))
```

output: `[(), 0, 8, 'hello', '']`

Comment: Thank you for your help! Yes I am a beginner :D. Can you explain why the new list is inside the def instead of outside.

Answer (score 0):

**@rody401**, you can try the below code.

```
def listmaking(l):
    b = [item for item in l if item != []]
    return b

b = listmaking ([44, 67, 87, 43, [], 3, [], 2]) 
print(b) # [44, 67, 87, 43, 3, 2]
```